# Python GRPC Client to remote server with different IP address

Tags: grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-python, grpcio

Is it possible to connect GPRC client in Python or any language to a remote server using DNS or an actual IP address?.
If you can provide a code snippet that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see this [example](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/basics/#creating-a-stub).

You would replace `localhost:50051` with the remote server's fully-qualified domain name (or IP address) and port.

Comment: This did not work. I have tried and still getting connection issues. Also, if the server has credentials how I can supply the credentials.

Comment: Please provide more information than "this did not work". What exactly did you try? What output|logs were produced by the client and server? Providing credentials is a different question and is explained on the site that I referenced: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/